# Why do I need to cast this boolean expression?

Tags: php

In PHP 7, the following snippet strangely prints `true`:

```
$b = true and false;
var_dump($b);
```

However, if I cast it, it correctly prints `false`:

```
$b = (bool)(true and false);
var_dump($b);
```

What is the phenomenon that causes this to happen?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php `and` has a lower precedence than `=`, so what you basically do is: `($b = true) and false` you see this when you do: `var_dump($b = true and false);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the cast that's doing it, it's the parentheses. `and` has lower precedence than `=`, so your first statement is treated as

```
($b = true) and false;
```

You need to write:

```
$b = (true and false);
```

or

```
$b = true && false;
```

`&&` and `and` are equivalent except for their precedence (the same goes for `||` and `or`).

Answer (score 4):

It's not the casting, but the parentheses:

```
$b = (true and false);
var_dump($b);
# => bool(false)
```

This is because [`=` binds more tightly than `and` or `or`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Alternatively, this also works:

```
$b = true && false;
var_dump($b);
# => bool(false)
```

`&&` and `||` bind more tightly than `=`.